# Knex migrations don't create anything

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to get started with Knex.js and I cant seem to get any migrations to work. When I run the command `knex migrate:latest` the database only has the `knex_migrations` table.

Am I doing something wrong?

#### Knexfile

```
module.exports = {
  development: {
    client: 'postgresql', //Also tried just 'pg'
    connection: {
      host: process.env.SERVER_HOST,
      user: process.env.SERVER_USER,
      password: process.env.SERVER_PASSWORD,
      database: 'mika_personal'
    }
  }
}
```

#### Migration

```
'use strict'

exports.up = function(knex, Promise) {
  knex.schema.createTable('blog_posts', function(table) {
    table.increments('id').primary()

    table.string('name', 75)
      .index()
      .unique()
      .notNullable()

    table.text('content')
    table.integer('views') 

    table.timestamps()
  })
}

exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  knex.schema.dropTable('blog_posts')   
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `return` to the first line of both of your up and down functions so knex gets access to the promise that `knex.schema.*` returns, then knex can use this to coordinate executing the migration. For example:

```
exports.down = function(knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema.dropTable('blog_posts')   
}
```